# OpenLayers function to switch many layers on by a loop

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, openlayers, layer

I have a layer switch control contains (dates) named (`yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss`) and they are working properly when I click on them.

Also, I have labels to enter(start) and(end) and a button to loop layers between these two values.

What I need is a `function`  to make this button activate the layers (dates) or make them switched on by loop with interval

PS: here we can use `title` as refernce and `displayInLayerSwitcher,true` and `setVisible(true)`

My code as follows

```js
singleLayer = {}
singleLayer['1'] = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: "1",
   baseLayer: false,
   visible: false,
   source: new ol.source.XYZ({
   projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    wrapX: false,
    url: 'folder/yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
   })
 })
singleLayer['2'] = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: "2",
   baseLayer: false,
   visible: false,
   source: new ol.source.XYZ({
   projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    wrapX: false,
    url: 'folder/yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
   })
  })

 singleLayer['3'] = new ol.layer.Tile({
   title: "3",
    baseLayer: false,
    visible: false,
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
     wrapX: false,
     url: 'folder/yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
    })
  })
      })


 var dates = new ol.layer.Group({
  openInLayerSwitcher: false,
  visible: false,
  layers:[
   singleLayer['1'],
   singleLayer['2'],
   singleLayer['3'],
  ]
 });
```

```html
<p>Loop Layers<p>
              <p>From date: <input type="text" name="fromdate" id="fromdate" value="yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss"></p>
              <p>To date: <input type="text" name="todate" id="todate" value="yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss"></p>
              <button onclick="loopLayer()">Loop layer by time interval</button>
              
function loopLayer() {
  .........
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var time = new ol.layer.Group({ ....... });

let intervalHandle = null;
let activeLayerIndex = -1;

function startAnimation() {
  // check if interval is already running
  if (!intervalHandle) {
    activeLayerIndex = 0;
    // make sure all layers of the group are hidden
    time.getLayers().forEach(layer => layer.setVisible(false));

    intervalHandle = setInterval(function() {
      const allLayers = time.getLayers();
      if (activeLayerIndex >= allLayers.getLength()) {
        // we reached the end, stop animating
        stopAnimation();
      }
      allLayers.item(activeLayerIndex).setVisible(true);

      if (activeLayerIndex > 0) {
        // hide the previous layer
        allLayers.item(activeLayerIndex -1).setVisible(false);
      }
      activeLayerIndex += 1;
    }, 500 /* milliseconds */);
  }
}

function stopAnimation() {
  if(intervalHandle) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
    intervalHandle = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I got an error (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'allLayers[activeLayerIndex].setVisible'))

Comment: Oops, my bad. getLayers() returns a collection, not an array. Fixed

Comment: ok, it works now, but there are two problems . First (I have to switch on first manually the time group in the layerswitchcontrol so we need to add in the function to switch it before the loop works. Second, just one layer shows and not show the other layers!

Comment: to show the group per default, remove the `visible: false,` from it or do a `time.setVisible(true)` inside the `startAnimation`. If you want to continue showing layers without hiding the previously shown layers, just remove or comment the part with the comment `// hide the previous layer` (line 23 to 26)

Comment: I mean that the function show just one layer and stopped, doesn't go show other layers, so I comment the lines as below and it works fine, also it stops automatically when it reaches the end

Comment: I am sorry, that if statement was inversed! Commenting it is a bad idea, it would create a `zombie`, since it never stops (or only when it somehow throws an error). Fixed it.